# How to forward logs with Splunk Forwarder for the files with no header and logs should be in form of key/Value

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have a splunk forwarder setup already on my host.

I have certain files in the folder **(/tom/mike/)**. File names are starting with Back*.

The content of file may in one or multiple line. There are multiple fixed position values separated with some spaces in each line with no header.

Content (Example: Consider "-" as one space)

```
Tom---516-----RTYUI------45678

Mik---345-----XYXFF------56789
```

I need splunk logs for each line.

like:

```
Key1= Tom  Key2=516  Key3= RTYUI  Key4= 45678

Key1= Mike  Key2= 345  Key3= XYXFF  Key4= 56789
```

I know **inputs.conf** changes would be like below:

```
[monitor:///tom/mike/Back*]

index=myIndex

blacklist=\.(gz|zip|bkz|arch|etc)$

sourcetype = BackFileData
```

Please suggest changes which can be done in props.conf. Please keep in mind that delimiter is fixed for each value in line but its not same (like 2 spaces)  for all column values. There are no headers as well in these files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `kvdelims` if you want a search-time extraction or you can make a transforms.conf rule and apply it in `props.conf` and it will extract at index time

Here's a good article covering all those scenarios

https://www.splunk.com/blog/2008/02/12/delimiter-based-key-value-pair-extraction.html

Comment: How to make a transforms.conf rule and apply it in props.conf ?

Comment: They should be located on your indexer(s) under `/opt/splunk/etc/apps/<app-name>/local`